# Pandas - Identify Last Row by Date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, shift

I'm trying to accomplish two things in my Pandas dataframe:

1. Create new column **Last Row** ('Yes' or 'No') based on new DateCompleted
2. Capture the **next** transaction on the current row, unless it's a new DateCompleted (in which case mark as Null).

Original Dataset

```
        DateCompleted      TranNumber  Sales

    0   1/1/17 10:15AM     3133         130.31
    1   1/1/17 11:21AM     3531         103.12  
    2   1/1/17 12:31PM     3652         99.23  
    3   1/2/17 9:31AM      3689         83.22
    4   1/2/17 10:31AM     3701         29.93
    5   1/3/17 8:30AM      3709         31.31
```

Desired Output

```
        DateCompleted      TranNumber   Sales    NextTranSales  LastRow

    0   1/1/17 10:15AM     3133         130.31   103.12         No
    1   1/1/17 11:21AM     3531         103.12   99.23          No
    2   1/1/17 12:31PM     3652         99.23    NaN            Yes
    3   1/2/17 9:31AM      3689         83.22    29.93          No 
    4   1/2/17 10:31AM     3701         29.93    NaN            Yes
    5   1/3/17 8:30AM      3709         31.31    ...            No
```

I can get the NextTranSales based on:

```
 df['NextTranSales'] = df.Sales.shift(-1)
```

But I'm having trouble determining the last row in the DateCompleted group and marking NextTranSales as Null if it is the last row.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data frame has been sorted by the *DateCompleted* column, then you might just need `groupby.shift`:

```
date = pd.to_datetime(df.DateCompleted).dt.date    
df["NextTranSales"] = df.groupby(date).Sales.shift(-1)
```

[image]

If you need the `LastRow` column, you can find out the last row index with `groupby` and then assign `yes` to the rows:

```
last_row_index = df.groupby(date, as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.index[-1])
df["LastRow"] = "No"
df.loc[last_row_index, "LastRow"] = "Yes"
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE:* This depends on `Sales` being free of `NaN`.  If it has any `NaN` we will get erroneous determinations of last row. This happens because I'm leveraging the convenience that the shifted column leaves a `NaN` in the last position.

```
d = df.DateCompleted.dt.date
m = {True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}
s = df.groupby(d).Sales.shift(-1)
df = df.assign(NextTranSales=s).assign(LastRow=s.isnull().map(m))
print(df)

        DateCompleted  TranNumber   Sales  NextTranSales LastRow
0 2017-01-01 10:15:00        3133  130.31         103.12      No
1 2017-01-01 11:21:00        3531  103.12          99.23      No
2 2017-01-01 12:31:00        3652   99.23            NaN     Yes
3 2017-01-02 09:31:00        3689   83.22          29.93      No
4 2017-01-02 10:31:00        3701   29.93            NaN     Yes
5 2017-01-03 08:30:00        3709   31.31            NaN     Yes
```

---

We can be free of the ***no*** `NaN` restriction with this

```
d = df.DateCompleted.dt.date
m = {True: 'Yes', False: 'No'}
s = df.groupby(d).Sales.shift(-1)
l = pd.Series(
    'Yes', df.groupby(d).tail(1).index
).reindex(df.index, fill_value='No')
df.assign(NextTranSales=s).assign(LastRow=l)

        DateCompleted  TranNumber   Sales  NextTranSales LastRow
0 2017-01-01 10:15:00        3133  130.31         103.12      No
1 2017-01-01 11:21:00        3531  103.12          99.23      No
2 2017-01-01 12:31:00        3652   99.23            NaN     Yes
3 2017-01-02 09:31:00        3689   83.22          29.93      No
4 2017-01-02 10:31:00        3701   29.93            NaN     Yes
5 2017-01-03 08:30:00        3709   31.31            NaN     Yes
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks again for helping me-you helped earlier this week :)